# Is it possible to extract row from QListWidgetItem*

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListWidgetItem* and wanted to know if its possible to extract the row from this pointer without iterating over the entire list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function below if you need the row number:

```
int QListWidget::row(const QListWidgetItem *) const
```

It's not from the pointer alone, but you do not need to iterate.

Comment: For "direct"ish access, you can use [QListWidgetItem::listWidget()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qlistwidgetitem.html#listWidget), as in `item->listWidget()->row(item)`.